# Is there a driver like this for Windows XP too?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card

In Ubuntu, there is a modified non-proprietary Nvidia driver preinstalled.
This driver helps me get the full native resolution (1920x1020) of my flatscreen displayed without errors, while my Graphics Card (Geforce FX 5200) only supports DVI-resolutions up to 1440x900. This is a very cool thing.

My question is: Is there such a kind of driver also for Windows XP?
I've already tried the omega drivers, but 1920x1020 looks awful on Windows.

Comment: Did you see this thread...http://www.w7forums.com/nvidia-geforce-fx-5200-driver-resolution-issue-t1762.html

Comment: Strange they made a driver for W98...http://nvidia.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/nvidia.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=2054

Answer (score 0):

Some say this driver works for XP and that resolution.

http://www.nvidia.com/object/winxp_2k_61.77.html

[Source](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3515/t/18351466.aspx)

Comment: sadly, this driver produces the same effect :<

Comment: Sometimes changing the refresh rate will enable other resolutions.